# Material ui Table, cell edit date validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, material-ui

I am using Material Table https://github.com/mbrn/material-table, my question is

> How to do validation of dates[active-inactive] when you edit a cell?

My code:

```
{ title: 'Active', field: 'active', type: "date"},
{ title: 'Inactive', field: 'inactive', type: "date",
            editComponent: props => (
              <input 
                type="date"
                value={props.value}
                onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
                min={props.rowData.active}
                InputProps={{inputProps: {min: props.rowData.active}}}
            />)},
```

I am using this code but doesn't work, still allows me to choose inactive dates before active. I put min(active), does anyone has any ideas of how to do this problem? Thanks